# Get unique rows of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to compare two tables that has the same columns but different number of rows. How do I find which rows are unique to each table? I found some join tutorials but it needs primary key to join two tables, my sample tables have no relation to each other.

Sample table:

```
TableA
Id | Name
1 | Person1
2 | Person2
3 | Person3
4 | Person4

TableB
Id | Name
1 | Person1
2 | Person2
4 | Person4

Sample result:
Id | Name
3 | Person3

Optional result:
Id | Name | Table
3 | Person3 | TableA
```

Comment: seeing your comment somewhere, you have mentioned that the two tables have no relationship with each other, you can still join both tables provided that on the `ON` clause, you must check all the value of the columns to the other tables. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query selects rows from TableA that are not present in TableB plus the rows from TableB not present in TableA, using a UNION statement.

```
SELECT Id, Name, 'TableA' FROM TableA
WHERE (Id, Name) NOT IN
(SELECT Id, Name FROM TableB)
UNION
SELECT Id, Name, 'TableB' FROM TableB
WHERE (Id, Name) NOT IN
(SELECT Id, Name FROM TableA)
```

Comment: It's generally best to add some explanation along with the code, telling the person asking the question why it works, linking to docs, etc. Also helps your code not get flagged by the low quality post review system. See @JohnWoo's answer for how to do it.

Comment: @CraigRinger I can't use John Woo's query because it requires realtionship from two tables

Comment: @CraigRinger Don't worry, I can understand Mariano's query, straight tot the point.. :)

Comment: @Blackator No worries, that's really for Mariano as a style thing when answering. Code-only posts get flagged by the moderator system and it's often helpful to offer just a line or two of hint - for other readers, not just the person asking the question.

Comment: It's been so long since I answered a question here I forgot about the protocol. I'll update the answer with a couple of comments.

Comment: @Blackator mariano's answer is equivalent to mine except that i have join both tables, as you can see i have check all the column names from both tables. Maybe you have seen join on my answer but it does not mean that It has relationship with each other because in the `ON` clause i have included all the columns in the table, same as mariano's answer which compares all columns but only using `NOT IN`. :)

Comment: Why you think simple UNION of 2 table (without NOT IN) will not work for this?

Answer (score 3):

Since MySQL lacks `FULL JOIN`, you can still simulate it using `LEFT or RIGHT` join with `UNION`. Try,

```
SELECT  a.* , 'TableA' as `Table`
FROM    tableA a
        LEFT JOIN tableB b
            ON a.id = b.id AND
               a.name = b.name
WHERE   b.id IS NULL
UNION
SELECT  d.*, 'TableB' as `Table`
FROM    tableA c
        RIGHT JOIN tableB d
            ON c.id = d.id AND
               c.name = d.name
WHERE   c.id IS NULL
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e66e/1)

Comment: @Blackator try this answer, i have added some rows on the tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.columns
Where table_name="table_1" AND
COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name="table_2")
```

We are getting the column names from the first table with the condition of (the sub query) not having the same columns(fields) in the second. So this give us those fields which are unique to first table, as you also wanted in your question.

Comment: It's generally best to add some explanation along with the code, telling the person asking the question why it works, linking to docs, etc. Also helps your code not get flagged by the low quality post review system. See @JohnWoo's answer for how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple query as

select * from tableA,tableB where tableA.Name Not In tableB.Name And tableB.Name Not In tableA.Name